# What is considered best practice for printing usage / help (--help)?

Tags: programming-practices, code-quality

When writing tools for the CLI of UNIX, how should I make the program print out help and/or usage?

I usually use `fprintf(stderr, "help text here");`, but there are several issues with that.

- First, I'm not sure, whether I should use `stderr`. Is that OK, or should I use `stdout`?
- As you can imagine, the help text is quite long, depending on how many options the tool has. Now, I usually, just put several `"strings like that\n"` in the second parameter. This however, fills my source code with fifty or more lines of help text. It is not easy manageable at all. What should I do instead?
- When a tool is not written in C or a C-like language, I tend to use [here-docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF) where possible (most prominently with Perl). I can't use that in C, but is there something like that, that I could use?
- I was considering putting it in a `headerfile.h` inside a `#define HELP "help text here"`, I've never seen it in the wild, don't know whether I should actually use that.

Ideally, I could put the text in an external file, and include it. Using `#include` for that seems wrong, though. What should I do then?

The idea is, to have a help text, that is easily manageable. Having it inside the source code isn't really convenient.

Comment: What's so bad about 50 lines in your source code? Just put it at the end. It's not like you're going to have to mess with it on a regular basis.

Comment: @whatsisname usage, help for normal and longopts. I end up having around 200 lines of strings in the sourcode. Aside from that, I just don't think this is best practice, etc. There must be a more efficient way of putting in help texts, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Inspire yourself from your target platform's internals

Have a look at the BSD's source code. For instance, here are the:

- `usage(void)` for NetBSD's `/usr/bin/uname` tool [[source](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/uname/uname.c?rev=1.11&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)]:

  ```
  usage(void)
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: uname [-amnprsv]\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ```
- `usage(void)` for NetBSD's `/usr/bin/telnet` [[source](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/telnet/main.c?rev=1.28&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)]
- `usage(void)` for OpenBSD's `/bin/ls` [[source](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/bin/ls/util.c?rev=1.15)]

## Have a look at alternatives

And decide for yourself whether they're better or worse. You can use Google CodeSearch to find others, like:

- SkyLoad's usage [[source](https://github.com/sugy/skyload/blob/master/utils.c#L416)]

As you can see, different style between these and the BSD systems integrated tools listed above. It doesn't mean you **have to** follow one or the other. But usually it's good to look around, and settle for the consistent solution.

#### A non-standard solution to the 50 lines of help...

If you don't like to avoid 50 lines of text, you could simply read the help from a text file (in plain text, or maybe directly parse the `man`'s source if you created one). I find that a rather elegant way (as you can even look up the text doc), however for core systems programs that would make them inherently unsafe and introduce a point of failure. Other people will argue it's heavy for a `usage` or `help` message, but it's not like these are called in fast tight loops...

***When in doubt, follow the giants.***

Answer (score 9):

I use `stdout`, because a help is not an error.

If this is a long help in C, I try to mimic here-docs:

```
printf("This is the help for MyWonderfulApp\n"
       "Options are:\n"
       "    --help: display what you are reading now\n"
       "    --quiet: output nothing\n");
```

But most of the time I write a `man` page using `nroff -man` dedicated tags. The in-app help simply consists in refering to that `man` page.

Comment: But help is not necessarily desirable standard output, is it? How about `stdlog`?

Comment: @greyfade: Is `stdlog` standard C?

Comment: @mouviciel: ... I thought it was. I guess not. C++ has a related standard stream (`cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, and `clog`), so I guess I thought `stdlog` was in the C standard. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

If I'd be you I'd just opened up sources of `grep`, `tail`, `cat`, `your_other_favorite_unix_shell_command` to see how it's done there. I'm pretty sure their ways are pretty well thought out and can be maintained by many people.

About `stderr` or `stdout`. It's really simple, if there's an error - write to `stderr`, if it's just info - `stdout`. For example, if I run your tool with wrong options, you might want to display an error, say `Use --help for usage`, this one belongs in `stderr`. If I run your tool with a valid option `--help`, please use `stdout`.

If it's your preference not to have long help strings near your code, don't. #define in a header file is perfectly fine, but it's really a personal preference. If I had to read the code of a command line tool I'd prefer its help string to be inside a file that handles options supplied by the user.

Comment: That doesn't answer his question.

Comment: Hm, what's up with the minus-ing? What for?

Comment: @Mavrik: the first paragraph does.

Answer (score 1):

I use the gnu [getopts](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) library. For an example with help, see this [sample project](https://github.com/srathbun/example-parser), specifically the main method at the bottom of [parser.y](https://github.com/srathbun/example-parser/blob/master/parser.y).

Since it is wrapped in curly braces, the vim editor I use can fold the lines together, and I don't even notice them when I don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

If I use C or prefer not to depend on Boost libraries, then I stick with GNU [`getopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html). Otherwise I prefer [Boost Program Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/program_options.html) which prints help automatically.

I also consider guessing the right option one of the best practices when it comes to options handling. I learned it from Git and now use the same in my projects. It basically uses Damerau–Levenshtein distance to print best matches if user enters some unknown command line option.

I wrote a [little article about this](http://741mhz.com/smart-getopt/) that you can use as an example.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, writing a hole page in **cout <<** or **printf()** code is cumbersome, particularly if you need to change and re-fill your paragraphs. Hence, it is obviously a good idea to edit that text in a separate file, using for example **emacs** where you can more easily format your text.

Then you can use the following **sed** script to convert that text file into a legal C header file:

```
s/\"/\\\"/g
s/$/\\n"/
s/^/"/
1i\
const char *helpStr = 
$a\
;
```

Then, upon **#include**-ing your header file into your source code, you can simply write out your text using

```
cout << helpStr;
```